# Meteor:search-source doesn´t clear the search

Tags: javascript, search, meteor, meteor-helper

I´m having some troubles with Meteor Search-source. The pagackage works fine, but I think that it has big leaks in the documentation. My problem right now is that I can´t clear the search when I don´t type any in the search field.
Currently the App show a list of websites. If I looking for some web in the search field, the App show me a list with results. But when I delete the characters in the field text (empty search), the list with results doesn´t disappear. It show the complete list of elements instead of show a empty list.
I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing works...
You can test typing for example "coursera" in the search field in my app, and next delete all types to check it out.

Some suggestion? Many thanks in advance

[My App](http://urco.meteor.com/)

**SERVER**

```
    SearchSource.defineSource('items', function(searchText, options) {
      var options = {sort: {upvote: -1}, limit: 20};
      // var options = options || {};

    if(searchText) {
      var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
      /*var selector = {title: regExp, description: regExp};*/
       var selector = {$or: [
      {title: regExp},
      {description: regExp}
    ]};
      return Websites.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else  {
      return Websites.find({}, options).fetch();

   }

 });

 function buildRegExp(searchText) {
     var words = searchText.trim().split(/[ \-\:]+/);
     var exps = _.map(words, function(word) {
    return "(?=.*" + word + ")";
  });
  var fullExp = exps.join('') + ".+";
  return new RegExp(fullExp, "i");
}
```

**CLIENTE**

```
//search function

var options = {
  keepHistory: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  localSearch: true
};

var fields = ['title','description'];

itemSearch = new SearchSource('items', fields, options);

//end search function



//search helper

Template.searchResult.helpers({

   getItems: function() {
    return itemSearch.getData({
        transform: function(matchText, regExp) {
            return matchText.replace(regExp, "$&")
            },
      sort: {upvote: -1}
    });
  },

  isLoading: function() {
    return itemSearch.getStatus().loading;
    }
});

// search events 

Template.searchBox.events({

      'keyup #search-box': _.throttle(function(e) {
        var text = $(e.target).val().trim();
        console.log(text);
        itemSearch.search(text,{}); 
      }, 200)
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="searchResult">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron searchResult">    
            <h3> Search results </h3>
                <ol>
                    {{#each getItems}}
                        {{> website_item_search}}       
                    {{/each}}
                </ol>
            <!--<div id="search-meta">
                {{#if isLoading}}
                    searching ...
                {{/if}}
            </div>-->
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you tried returning an empty array (or null) if the `searchText` is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Just by changing the code on server file, you should be able to see no results on blank text field.

Here is new code. https://github.com/ashish1dev/search_source_example

```
SearchSource.defineSource('packages', function(searchText, options) {
    var options = {sort: {isoScore: -1}, limit: 20};

    if(searchText.length>=1) {
        var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
        var selector = {$or: [
            {packageName: regExp},
            {description: regExp}
        ]};

    return Packages.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else if (searchText.length===0){ 
        return [];// return blank array when length of text searched is zero
  } 
  else {
        return Packages.find({}, options).fetch(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Great, it works!! I´m a newbie programmer and at the moment is a bit confused for me implement some logic operations... I tried too implementing a new else if like your solution, but my problem was that I didn´t know how to return a empty array... Thanks for the tip!! Im loving Meteor;)

Comment: Happy Meteor-ing ! :-)